# How to use named parameters and global vars with same name in Python?

Tags: python, global-variables, python-module

Example code from a module:

```
somevar = "a"

def myfunc(somevar = None):
    # need to access both somevars ???
    # ... if somevar was specified print it or use the global value
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    somevar = "b" # this is just for fun here
    myfunc("c")
    myfunc() # should print "a" (the value of global variable)
```

There are at least two reasons for using the same name:educational (to learn how to use local/globals) and usage in modules.

Let say that this code is part of your module: `mymodule` and you want to do things like:

```
import mymodule

mymodule.samevar = "default"
...
mymodule.myfunc(somevar = "a")
...
mymodule.myfunc()
```

As you can imagine in this example is simplified, imagine that `somevar` parameter is one of many optional parameters and that myfunc is called in many places.

Comment: Have you tried the keywords 'global' and 'local'?

Comment: should the second call really print "C", or should it be "a" instead?

Comment: @theomega : thanks for remarking this, I corrected the example.

Comment: @JGord, `local` is not a keyword, and `global`, as a keyword, means something different: that a variable the compiler would normally see as local, because it's assigned-to (or otherwise bound) in the function body, must instead be referenced and assigned at module level.  Maybe you mean built-in functions (**not** keywords!) `locals` and `globals`?  The former is unhelpful, the latter can indeed help, but, see my answer for details about _how_.

Comment: @Alex, yes locals and globals is what I meant. I put it in a comment because I only quickly read the question and didn't have time to actually think through a helpful response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By far the best approach, as the other answers say, is to avoid this very, very bad design: just don't use the same names for two different things!

If you're locked into this terrible design, maybe because your company's Supreme Architect decreed it and it's just non-negotiable (e.g., there's tons of customer code relying on the names of both the global and the parameter), the first order of business for you is to make sure your resume is up to date, print it on the best printer, and start getting in touch with members of your social network to look for a job at a place that's run more sensibly; next, to avoid losing health insurance until a better job is found, try

```
def myfunc(somevar = None):
    if somevar is None:
        print globals().get('somevar')
    else:
        print somevar
```

I've also renamed your `mufunc` to `myfunc` because that's the name it's being *called* with (though given the incredibly bad design your hypothetical Supreme Architect seems to be able to perpetrate, maybe he's *also* specified that the function be called by a different name from the one it's defined with?  seems to go with the systematic name conflict this hypothetical but already pretty hateful guy is assumed to have foisted on you!-).

Comment: You are really funny and helpful! I corrected the typos from the example. Now I will update the question and explain you why I was interested about using the same name.

Comment: @bogdan, thanks for the kudos _and_ the clarification. In Python idiom, when a value must have a general default value but can be overridden per-call with specific values, the former is usually named with a `default_` prefix -- for example, see the socket module, `getdefaulttimeout` and `setdefaulttimeout` functions and the `timeout` named parameter to various functions (using getter and setter functions in this case, rather than "just a global variable", is also common, since _modules_ can't use the `property` built-in, which is what lets you always avoid getters/setters in _classes_).

Answer (score 1):

Why does you local variable have to have the same name as the global variable? Renaming one of them seems like a simple solution. Another option is to pass the global variable in as a parameter, but this will still just give you a different variable name to access the save value.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. Rename the variable, ie to `somevar_`.
2. Move the global to a different module. You can write a module `myappdefaults`

   ```
   import myappdefaults
   print myappdefaults.somevar
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to do things.

```
somevar = "a"

def mufunc(_somevar = None):
    global somevar
    if _somevar:
        print _somevar
    else:
        print somevar

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global somevar
    somevar = "b"
    myfunc("c")
    myfunc() $ should print "c"
```